# Why do you subtract 1 in a leap year if the date falls before March?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calendar-computations

I was reading this below and I had a question:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220131007/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.calendar.html)

Take a look under "The Key Value Method" where it says "If your date is in January or February of a leap year, subtract 1."

I understand that this is a step that we had to follow but why do we need to subtract 1? I try to find it on google but had no luck.

again my question is: why do you subtract 1 in a leap year if the date falls before March?

Comment: This is more of a "programming with calendar dates" question, and it sounds like it is specific to a particular environment.  Can you elaborate within your question rather than depending on an external link?

Comment: Since knowing that it is a leap year will affect what day of the week it is for those dates in march, april, may, ..., december since there was an extra day in February which normally doesn't occur.  The formula they give goes ahead and assumes that day already occurred and has shifted the days of the week, but if you are in january or february, it hadn't yet so you need to undo the change by subtracting one.

Comment: A "why do you..." question depends essentially on the premise of what "you" were trying to accomplish.  Surely you suspect that it has something to do with Feb. 29th in a leap year?

Answer (score 0):

Because it will be leap year only if there is $29^{th}$  $ February$, which can not come before march (more precisely 29th feb).

So while calculating we need to subtract 1 as its not a leap year yet.